# ¿Cómo reiniciar los valores autoincrementables de una columna en una tabla?

Tags: sql, postgresql, autoincremento

Tengo una tabla en postgresql con las siguientes columnas

```
   Columna   |          Tipo          |
-------------+------------------------+
 id_empleado | integer                |
 nombre      | character varying(255) |
 apellido    | character varying(255) | 
 id_jefatura | integer                |
```

La columna `id_empleado` es autoincrementable y tiene valores que saltan entre si, por ejemplo del id 18 se salta al 32, y así.

Lo que quiero es actualizar ese columna, para que reinicie el id, y suba incrementalmente el valor, para no tener saltos de id tan altos.

Por ejemplo:

```
id_empleado  |          nombre        |
-------------+------------------------+
 18          | Pedro                  |
 32          | Pablo                  |
 34          | Luis                   | 
 45          | Andres                 |
```

Deberia quedar:

```
id_empleado  |          nombre        |
-------------+------------------------+
 1           | Pedro                  |
 2           | Pablo                  |
 3           | Luis                   | 
 4           | Andres                 |
```

Comment: Has eliminado registros de tu tabla?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con reiniciar? ¿Dejarlo en 1 o en el valor más alto existente?

Comment: ¿y eso no altera la integridad referencial de tu base de datos? ¿en qué lenguaje o solo con instrucciones de posgres?

Comment: @Shaz si quiero reiniciarlo a 1.

Comment: @ReneLimon no altera, ya que estoy insertando datos nuevos, no existen relaciones funcionales con otras tablas. Si fuera posible solo con postgres.

Comment: ¿Por qué tienes saltos tan altos en tu tabla? ¿Y es tu objetivo eliminar completamente los saltos?

Comment: @sstan tengo esos saltos por que estoy pasando unos datos de mysql a postgresql a traves de CSV, y estoy eliminando datos que tienen null, por eso quiero eliminar todos esos saltos, y reiniciarlos.

Comment: Solo lo menciono porque aunque los reinicializes, es 100% normal que con el tiempo vayas a volver a tener saltos.

Comment: @sstan tienes razón, eso no lo paso por alto, lo que pasa es que quiero iniciar esa tabla con datos limpios, independientemente de la manera que se eliminen o queden despues los datos deben seguir funcionando.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta instruccion podria funcionar:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE seq RESTART WITH 1;
UPDATE tu_tabla SET id_empleado=nextval('seq');
```

pero lo recomendable sería primero mover los ids a un indice muy alto y después regresarlos a uno para evitar la duplicidad de los ids:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE seq RESTART WITH 1;
UPDATE tu_tabla SET id_empleado=1000000+ nextval('seq');
```

Y después de esto ejecutar el primer script.

Comment: Gracias me sirvio tu respuesta, ahora pude probarla.

Answer (score 2):

Asumiendo que `id_empleado` es tu clave primaria, entonces, como bien nota @Rene Limon en su respuesta, si tratas de hacerle un `UPDATE` directo a la tabla con los nuevos valores, vas a recibir errores. Esto es debido a que *durante* el `UPDATE` se generan temporalmente entradas duplicadas, que de haberse completado el `UPDATE`, al final los valores hubieran sido correctos y únicos. Pero durante la *transición* a los nuevos valores, suceden duplicados que la clave primaria no permite.

Aunque su sugerencia de hacer un `UPDATE` preventivo es válido, otra manera de manejarlo, para evitar de hacer un `UPDATE` 2 veces, es de remover la clave primaria temporalmente, hacer el `UPDATE`, y luego volver a agregar la clave primaria.

Ejemplo (tienes que ajustar los nombres, por supuesto):

```
alter table empleado
drop constraint empleado_pk;

alter sequence empleado_id_empleado_seq restart with 1;

update empleado
  set id_empleado = nextval('empleado_id_empleado_seq');

alter table empleado
add constraint empleado_pk
primary key (id_empleado);
```

Comment: Gracias aunque use la respuesta de Rene, es bueno tener otras alternativas +1.

Answer (score 0):

Para reiniciar la secuencia de un autoincremento en postgres, debería funcionar de esta manera, voy a asumir que la tabla se llama `staff`, solo para mostrar la sintaxis:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE staff_id_empleado_seq RESTART WITH 1;
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-altersequence.html